# Using function returns in other calculations within same function

Tags: function, class, types, swiftui, calculation

I have calculated a value in a function within an ObservableObject class and I now want to use the value returned in another calculation within the class.

The code is below, things to note:-

1. hole1index is an item of data fetched from Core Data.
2. The first function (p1h1shots) works perfectly and returns the correct value.
3. The second function (p1h1net) needs to use the output from p1h1shots to calculate a return value.
4. I have tried to structure the second function in a number of ways but keep getting similar error messages along the lines of "Cannot convert value of type '(Int16) -> Int16' to expected argument type 'Int16' The code shown has this error message on the return line of p1h1net.

I am relatively new to Swiftui so may be missing something basic and any pointers or clues would be gratefully received. If any additional information would help please let me know.

Thanks in advance

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class ScoreManager : ObservableObject {
 
    @Published var player1 = ""
    @Published var player2 = ""
    @Published var p1handicap = 0
    @Published var p2handicap = 0
    @Published var p1hole1gross = 0
    @Published var p1hole2gross = 0
    
    func p1h1shots(hole1index: Int16) -> Int16 {
        
        let hand = Int16(p1handicap)
        let shot = hand - hole1index
  
        if shot < 0 {
            return Int16(0)
        }
        
        if shot < 0 {
            return Int16(0)
        }
        
        if shot >= 0 && shot < 18 {
            return Int16(1)
        }
        
        if shot >= 18 && shot < 36 {
            return Int16(2)
        }
        
        if shot >= 36 && shot < 54 {
            return Int16(3)
        }
        return Int16(0)
    }

func p1h1net() -> Int16 {
        
        let gross = Int16(p1hole1gross)
        let shot = p1h1shots
        
        return Int16(gross - shot)
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the second `if shot < 0` expression is redundant.

Without parentheses you are going to assign the **function** to `shot`, instead you have to call it with a parameter

```
let shot = p1h1shots(hole1index: someInt16)
```

And `p1h1shots` can be written more efficiently with a `switch`

```
func p1h1shots(hole1index: Int16) -> Int16 {

    let hand = Int16(p1handicap)
    let shot = hand - hole1index
    
    switch shot {
        case 0..<18: return 1 // the literal is returned as Int16
        case 18..<36: return 2
        case 36..<54: return 3
        default: return 0
    }
}
```

or still shorter

```
func p1h1shots(hole1index: Int16) -> Int16 {

    let hand = Int16(p1handicap)
    let shot = hand - hole1index
    
    return 0..<54 ~= shot ? shot / 18 + 1 : 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. The revised p1h1shots works perfectly and is a good learning for me. With regard to the revised code for shot I am getting an error of "Cannot find 'someInt16' in scope", is this a code item or should I be putting some sort of reference to an item in there, if so what should I be referencing?

Comment: `someInt16` is just a placeholder, I have no idea what the parameter is supposed to be, likely `gross` or maybe some literal.

Comment: vadian I have tried using the same code as I use to show the returned value in a view p1h1shots(hole1index: course.hole1index) where course is the Core Data entity where hole1index is stored but I then get an error of "cannot find 'course' in scope. If I add @ObservedObject var course: Course to bring it in scope I get an error of "Class 'ScoreManager' has no initializers". I have not used initializers before so am not sure what it needs, do you have any ideas from the info you have? If not I will have to do some research!! Thank you for your input so far it has been really helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with SwiftUI and this is another question.